# Provide custom registration fields in Woocommerce edit profile My account page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I am developing an e-commerce site in Wordpress using woo-commerce plugin, where I have added few additional fields in registration form like mobile number,gender and so on.How do I provide these fields in the edit profile of My account page in website to be edited by the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this example,

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form', 'my_woocommerce_edit_account_form' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details', 'my_woocommerce_save_account_details' );

function my_woocommerce_edit_account_form() {

$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$user = get_userdata( $user_id );

if ( !$user )
  return;

$twitter = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'twitter', true );
$url = $user->user_url;

?>

<fieldset>
<legend>Social information</legend>
<p>Fill in this information about your social media accounts.</p>
<p class="form-row form-row-thirds">
  <label for="twitter">Twitter Username:</label>
  <input type="text" name="twitter" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $twitter ); ?>" class="input-text" />
</p>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>Additional Information</legend>
<p class="form-row form-row-thirds">
  <label for="url">Website:</label>
  <input type="text" name="url" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $url ); ?>" class="input-text" />
</p>
</fieldset>

<?php
}

function my_woocommerce_save_account_details( $user_id ) {

update_user_meta( $user_id, 'twitter', htmlentities( $_POST[ 'twitter' ] ) );

$user = wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user_id, 'user_url' => esc_url( $_POST[ 'url' ] ) ) );

}
```

For more information,

- [Custom User Fields on Woocommerce My Account Page](http://bitsandbabble.com/2014/10/custom-user-fields-on-woocommerce-my-account-page/)
- [Custom WooCommerce User Account Fields](https://iconicwp.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-adding-custom-woocommerce-user-account-fields/)
- [add user custom field in My Account page in Woocommerce?](https://www.techiecorner.com/3337/how-to-add-user-custom-field-in-my-account-page-in-woocommerce/)

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Thank u .It worked for me.

Comment: Ok, then accept the answer. So, it may help others also.

Comment: I have accepted.